# Backbone.js - can't fetch data, or bind to the fetch event on collection?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm using jQuery 1.7.1, Underscore 1.3.1 and Backbone 0.9.1. This is my Backbone code, in full:

```
$(function(){
  window.Student = Backbone.Model.extend({
  });
  window.Students = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Student, 
  });
  window.AllStudents = new Students();
  AllStudents.url = "/init.json";
  AllStudents.bind('reset', function() { 
      console.log('hello world');  
  }); 
  AllStudents.fetch();
  AllStudents.fetch({ url: "/init.json", success: function() {
      console.log(AllStudents);
  }, failure: function() { 
      console.log('failure');
  }});
  AllStudents.fetch({ url: "/init.json" }).complete(function() {
      console.log(AllStudents);
  });
});
```

Only one console statement even appears, in the third `.fetch()` call, and then it's an empty object.

I'm baffled. What am I doing wrong? How can I bind to the reset event, and work with the fetched data?

This is the JSON file:

```
[
  { text: "Amy", freq_2011: 5 },
  { text: "Angeline", freq_2011: 26 },
  { text: "Anna", freq_2011: 55 }    
]
```

I have checked that the JSON file is being served as application/json, and I can also see that it is being fetched by the XHR request, three times.

UPDATE: This is my HTML, in full:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container"></div>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.1/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.1/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can others reproduce the problem?

Comment: Have you tried setting the url parameter inside the definition of the collection itself?

Comment: Yes, doesn't help :( Please could someone else try the code and see if they can reproduce the problem?

Comment: I got around this by using bootstrapped models in the end: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#FAQ-bootstrap I've still absolutely no idea what was going wrong, though.

Answer (score 1):

Backbone has a nice function which can be overridden called [parse](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-parse) which gets the fetched data as its arguments once a successful fetch is called. You can use this to process your JSON once its loaded for instance:

```
window.Students = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Student,
    parse: function(response) {
       console.log(response,response.results);
       return response.results;
  }
});
```